# Route URL laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

How can I do this in Laravel 4

```
  URL::route('auth.reset', array('kh34KHh4K342'))
```

Instead of

```
 http://domain.tld/auth/reset?kh34KHh4K342
```

I want to get this :

```
 http://domain.tld/auth/reset/kh34KHh4K342
```

#### EDIT

This my routes.php :

The problem is because I have two routes with the same name? How do you explain that ?

Should i set a different name event is the same kind, and different methods

```
    // Set locale
  $locale = Request::segment(1);

    if(in_array($locale, Config::get('app.languages'))) {
\App::setLocale($locale);
  } else {
$locale = null;
  }
    Route::group(
array( 'prefix' => $locale ), function () {

    Route::get('/'), array( 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex', 'as' => '/' ));

    // Auth
    Route::group(
        array( 'prefix' => 'auth' ), function () {

            // Login
            Route::get(
                'login', array( 'before' => 'guest',
                                'uses'   => 'UserController@getLogin',
                                'as'     => 'auth.login' )
            );

            Route::post(
                'login', array( 'before' => 'guest|csrf',
                                'uses'   => 'UserController@postLogin',
                                'as'     => 'auth.login' )
            );

   Route::get(
                'reset/{$token}', array( 'uses'   => 'UserController@getReset',
                                'as'     => 'auth.reset' )
            );
   Route::post(
                'reset', array( 'uses'   => 'UserController@postReset',
                                'as'     => 'auth.reset' )
            );

         }
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
URL::route('auth.reset', array('kh34KHh4K342'))
```

to

```
URL::route('auth.reset', 'kh34KHh4K342')
```

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: post your full routes file

Comment: i need your full routes file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

In your routes.php

```
 Route::controller('auth', 'AuthController');
```

In your Controller

```
 class AuthController extends BaseController {

   public function getReset($hashcode) {
     ...code here
   }


 }
```

and it will look like this `http://domain.tld/auth/reset/<hascode>`